# SQL Server - Standard Deviation in a Windowed Query

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server provides the [`STDEV` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stdev-transact-sql), but it cannot be used in conjunction with [window functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql).

For example

```
SELECT
     TestName
    ,[BatchSize]
    ,[NumIterations] = COUNT(*)
    ,[Min] = MIN(RuntimeMs)
    ,[Average] = AVG(RuntimeMs)
    ,[Max] = MAX(RuntimeMs)
    ,[StdDev] = STDEV(RuntimeMs)
FROM #TimingResult
GROUP BY TestName, [BatchSize]
```

How can I compute percentiles and standard deviation at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://community.teradata.com/t5/Analytics/standard-deviation-function-with-parition-by/td-p/1946). Essentially, you have to compute it [using statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Definition_of_population_values):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TestName
    ,[BatchSize]
    ,[Iterations] = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY TestName, [BatchSize])
    ,[Min] = PERCENTILE_DISC(0) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY RuntimeMs) OVER(PARTITION BY TestName, [BatchSize])
    ,[5th] = PERCENTILE_DISC(0.05) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY RuntimeMs) OVER(PARTITION BY TestName, [BatchSize])
    ,[10th] = PERCENTILE_DISC(0.1) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY RuntimeMs) OVER(PARTITION BY TestName, [BatchSize])
    ,[25th] = PERCENTILE_DISC(0.25) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY RuntimeMs) OVER(PARTITION BY TestName, [BatchSize])
    ,[Avg] = PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY RuntimeMs) OVER(PARTITION BY TestName, [BatchSize])
    ,[75th] = PERCENTILE_DISC(0.75) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY RuntimeMs) OVER(PARTITION BY TestName, [BatchSize])
    ,[90th] = PERCENTILE_DISC(0.9) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY RuntimeMs) OVER(PARTITION BY TestName, [BatchSize])
    ,[95th] = PERCENTILE_DISC(0.95) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY RuntimeMs) OVER(PARTITION BY TestName, [BatchSize])
    ,[Max] = PERCENTILE_DISC(1) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY RuntimeMs) OVER(PARTITION BY TestName, [BatchSize])
    ,[StdDev] = SQRT((
        (COUNT(RuntimeMs) OVER (PARTITION BY TestName, [BatchSize])
        * SUM(RuntimeMs*RuntimeMs) OVER (PARTITION BY TestName, [BatchSize]))
        - POWER(SUM(RuntimeMs) OVER (PARTITION BY TestName, [BatchSize]), 2))
        / (COUNT(RuntimeMs) OVER (PARTITION BY TestName, [BatchSize])
        * COUNT(RuntimeMs) OVER (PARTITION BY TestName, [BatchSize]) - 1))
FROM #TimingResult
```

P.S. Feel free to use this statement when performance testing code. That's why I wrote it <sub>(in particular for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50841951/2799848))</sub>.